# If the true population mean is 43 and the significance level is 5%, the probability of a Type II error is closest to:

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, hypothesis-testing

A normal population has a population standard deviation of $12$. The hypotheses about the population mean, $H_0: \mu = 40$ versus $H_1: \mu > 40$ are to be tested. A random sample of $100$ observations will be selected and the sample mean is denoted by $\bar x$.

If the true population mean is $43$ and the significance level is $5\%$, the probability of a Type II error is closest to:

A. $0.305$

B. $0.273$

C. $0.229$

D. $0.195$

E. $0.187$

I know that the $z$ score is $(43-40)/1.2 = 2.50$, but am lost on what to do afterwards

Answer (score 2):

The Type II error $\beta$ is the probability of failing to reject the null hypothesis $H_0$ when the alternative $H_1 : \mu = 43$ is true.  In other words, given that the true sampling distribution of the sample mean is normal with mean $\mu = 43$ and standard error $\sigma/\sqrt{n} = 12/\sqrt{100} = 1.2$, then $H_0$ is not rejected if it is "too small."  But what does this mean?

Specifically, suppose we observe a value of the test statistic $$Z \mid H_0 = \frac{\bar x - \mu_0}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}} = \frac{\bar x - 40}{1.2}$$ such that it is less than the critical value for rejection at the $\alpha = 0.05$ level; i.e., $$\frac{\bar x - 40}{1.2} \le z^*_\alpha \approx 1.64485.$$  This means the sample mean would need to be at most $$\bar x \le 41.9738,$$ otherwise you would reject.  So we need to compute $$\beta = \Pr[\bar x \le 41.9738 \mid H_1] = \Pr\left[\frac{\bar x - 43}{1.2} \le \frac{41.9738 - 43}{1.2}\right] = \Pr[Z \le -0.855146] \approx 0.196235.$$  Therefore, the Type II error probability is just shy of $20\%$.

The thinking is like this:  The test statistic assumes the null is true.  Under this assumption, what is the *complement* of the rejection region; i.e., for what values of the sample mean would we *not* reject the null?  Then, assuming the alternative hypothesis is true, what is the chance of observing a sample mean that lies in the complement of the rejection region?  This gives you the probability of committing a Type II error--failure to reject when we should reject.

Comment: Just one quick question, how did you get from Pr[Z less than or equal to -855146] to equal 0.196235? Any table you have that gave you that?

Comment: check out question above @heropup